# Why aren't the colours in my res file being recognised?

Tags: android, colors

I'm getting this error in my code:

Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value @color/red').

Here is my TextView:

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tv01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/prizeFund"
    android:background="@color/red">
</TextView>
```

And the color definition, in colors.xml in res/values:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="red">#ff0000</color>
<color name="green">#00ff00</color>
<color name="blue">#0000ff</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: have you run "clean" since adding the file?  Sometimes need a clean to refresh all the resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clean your project The `R.java` file will be regenerated for you

On eclipse go to Project---->Clean..

also the resources must be in strings.xml not colors.xml

below an exemple of the strings.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
       <!-- Strings Resources -->
    <string name="animations">Animations: </string>
    <string name="compass">Compass: </string>

     <!-- Colors Resources -->
    <color name="opaque_white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
    <color name="gray">#FF888888</color>
</resources>
```